# objective-c Accessing array given as value of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

let's say i have a nsdictionary which contains an array as value.

```
NSMutableDictionary *test = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:"@Audi",@"Mercedes",@"Ferrari",nil], @"box 1",
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:"@Chervrolet",@"Mercedes",@"Bentley",nil], @"box 2",
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:"@Audi",@"Dodge",@"Ferrari",nil], @"box 2",
nil]
```

that's my simple dictionary with the arrays inside.
well now i need to check if theres a value in it.

here how i check if theres a certain key

```
if([test objectForKey@"box 2"]) { NSLog(@"item exists"); }
```

how can i access now the array inside one of the value? let's say to check if the array contains an item or to add one?

let's say i want to check if box 2 contains an Audi, and if not, i want to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `containsObject` you can check if object exist in array.

```
       if([[test valueForKey:@"box 2"] containsObject:@"Audi"])
           NSLog(@"Audi exists");
       else
       {
           //[[test valueForKey:@"box 2"] addObject:@"Audi"];

           //EDIT
           NSMutableArray *data = [test valueForKey:@"box 2"];
           [data addObject:@"Audi"];
           [test setObject:data forKey:@"box 2"];

           NSLog(@"Add Audi");
       }
```

Comment: ok thanks that works... but how to add the object to the array? i can't get an instance name to call the array. i tried using [test valueforkey] addObject but wont consider it an array object so won't work, there is no way i can call the instance of that array?

Comment: Don't need to set object again after retrieving it